# Jekyll filter categories and posts by tags

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

In Jekyll I filter posts by tags displating a list of the posts which have the assigned tag like this:

```
---
layout: layout
---
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% for tag in post.tags %}
{% if tag == page.tag %}

<li itemprop="name" itemprop=name>{{ post.title }}</li>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Burt what I'd like to do is display the categories which have posts of the tag and the posts listed under each category.

---

### Example use case

Category 1 has post 1, post 2, post 3.
Category 2 has post 4, post 5, post 6.
Category 3 has post 7

Posts 1,2,4 have tag Tag1.

The tag page should display Category 1 + Post 1, post 2.  Category 2 + Post 4.

---

On the homepage I display categories with all posts under each category like this:

```
{% assign counter=0 %}
<main id="page" role="main">
{% for category in site.categories %}
<div class="col pane ui-layout-{% assign counter=counter | plus:1 %}" id="{{ page.id }}">
    <div class="colheader">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <p class="lead">Leadin text</p>
        <h1>{{ category | first }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="colscroll unlock">
{% for posts in category %}
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="colblock" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">    
        <div class="excerpt">
            <time class="date" datetime="{{ page.date | '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S-08:00' }}" itemprop="datePublished">
                {{ page.date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}
            </time>
        <h1>
            <a itemprop="url" href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank" title="{{ post.title }}">
                <span itemprop="name" itemprop=name>{{ post.title }}</span>
            </a>
        </h1>                        
        <p itemprop="description">
            {{ post.excerpt }}..
        </p>
        <p class="link_tags">{{ page.tags }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</main>
```

So on the tag page I try to achieve what I want like this but it is returning all categories and all posts just like the homepage rather than filtering by the tag.

```
---
layout: layout
---
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% for tag in post.tags %}
{% if tag == page.tag %}


{% assign counter=0 %}
<main id="page" role="main">
{% for category in site.categories %}
<div class="col pane ui-layout-{% assign counter=counter | plus:1 %}" id="{{ page.id }}">
    <div class="colheader">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <p class="lead">Leadin text</p>
        <h1>{{ category | first }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="colscroll unlock">

{% for posts in category %}
{% for post in post.tags %}
        <div class="colblock" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">    
            <div class="excerpt">
                <time class="date" datetime="{{ page.date | '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S-08:00' }}" itemprop="datePublished">
                    {{ page.date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}
                </time>
                <h1>
                    <a itemprop="url" href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank" title="{{ post.title }}">
                        <span itemprop="name" itemprop=name>{{ post.title }}</span>
                    </a>
                </h1>                        
                <p itemprop="description">
                    {{ post.excerpt }}..
                </p>
                <p class="link_tags">{{ page.tags }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</main>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I alsio tried this but it returns a blank page

```
---
layout: layout
---
<ul>
{% for post in site.posts %}
{% for tag in post.tags %}
{% if tag == page.tag %}


{% assign counter=0 %}
<main id="page" role="main">
{% for category in tag.categories %}
<div class="col pane ui-layout-{% assign counter=counter | plus:1 %}" id="{{ page.id }}">
    <div class="colheader">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <p class="lead">Leadin text</p>
        <h1>{{ category | first }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="colscroll unlock">

{% for posts in category %}
{% for post in tag.posts %}
        <div class="colblock" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">    
            <div class="excerpt">
                <time class="date" datetime="{{ page.date | '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S-08:00' }}" itemprop="datePublished">
                    {{ page.date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}
                </time>
                <h1>
                    <a itemprop="url" href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank" title="{{ post.title }}">
                        <span itemprop="name" itemprop=name>{{ post.title }}</span>
                    </a>
                </h1>                        
                <p itemprop="description">
                    {{ post.excerpt }}..
                </p>
                <p class="link_tags">{{ page.tags }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</main>

{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

[The live site template is up on Github](http://dcondrey.github.io). (tags list is the second circular icon from the left at the top of the page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```html
---
layout: default
---

<main id="page" role="main">
{% for category in site.categories %}
    {% assign counter=0 %}
    {% for posts in category %}
        {% for post in posts %}
            {% if post.tags contains page.tag %}
                {% assign counter=counter | plus:1 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}

{% if counter != 0 %}

<div class="col pane ui-layout-{% assign counter=counter | plus:1 %}" id="{{ page.id }}">
    <div class="colheader">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <p class="lead">Leadin text</p>
        <h1>{{ category | first }}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="colscroll unlock">
{% for posts in category %}
{% for post in posts %}
{% if post.tags contains page.tag %}
    <div class="colblock" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
        <div class="excerpt">
            <time class="date" datetime="{{ page.date | '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%S-08:00' }}" itemprop="datePublished">
                {{ page.date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}
            </time>
        <h1>
            <a itemprop="url" href="{{ post.url }}" target="_blank" title="{{ post.title }}">
                <span itemprop="name" itemprop=name>{{ post.title }}</span>
            </a>
        </h1>
        <p itemprop="description">
            {{ post.excerpt }}..
        </p>
        <p class="link_tags">{{ page.tags }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</main>
```

I've just modified your homepage code.

**Edit**: *Added conditional code. Print only categories that contains posts with current tag.*

Comment: Hey David, thanks.. but not quite.. The part I'm stuck on is displaying only the category columns which have posts of the selected tag.  The way it is now, it generates all the category columns and displays the posts which match the selected tag.  I need to also filter the categories so as to avoid several empty columns that need not be displayed.

Comment: I have pushed your suggested code to the repo though so you can see it live if you like.  I think this may be stretching the intended purposes of Jekyll.